# How to catch wrapped exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I am creating a wrapper over a library. The library throws multiple kinds of exception: 
`A B C D E F.`

Some types are retriable and others are not. To simplify exception handling for the clients of the wrapper, I am wrapping the exceptions into two kinds of checked exceptions: 
`RetriableException and Exception.`

Therefore signature of any function in my library looks like:

```
public void foo() throws RetriableException, Exception {
   ...
}
```

However the clients of the wrapper should be able to directly catch exception A, B, C .. as well in case they want to take some specific action on them.

```
try {
  wrapper.foo()
} catch (A e) {
  doSomething()
}
```

How should I model this behavior?

One way is to ask clients to do exception.getCause() but it doesn't feel intuitive.

Comment: Is the logic you use in your wrapper something you might extract as a static method e.g. `ExceptionInspector.isRetrieable()`?

Comment: Extend your summary to display actual exceptions thrown.

Comment: Thus "To simplify exception handling for the clients of the wrapper, I am wrapping the exceptions" but clients of the wrapper should be able to directly catch exception A, B, C ..."  These 2 statements are a contradiction. Maybe you need to rethink your requirements, not wrap it al all?

Comment: Maybe wrap them grouped in few wrapper exceptions based the business logic(on how you want to catch them from client)